# jquery change click function of a link by changing class

Tags: jquery

OK, I'm just getting to grips with jQuery and have a little issue.

I have a link that will change the contents of a `<div>` with a textarea

```
<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

On click I want the save link to change the contents of the textarea in the original `<div>` heres the code I have for this

```
$(function(){
   var content = $('.edit').text();

   $('.edit').click(function(){
      $('.content').html('<textarea class="text">' + content + '</textarea>');
      $('.text').focus();
      $(this).removeClass('edit').addClass('save').text('Save');
   }

   $('.save').live('click', function(){

      $('.content').html($('.text').val()); 
      $(this).removeClass('save').addClass('edit').text('Edit');          

       // Ajax code to save new content

   });

});
```

My problem is when I click the Edit button because I add the class `save` it also executes the `.save` click function. How can make sure the .save function is only executed when I click the save function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach your click event-handler to the `a` element itself, then check whether or not it has the class of 'edit' or 'save', and perform actions based on that eventuality:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')){
            $(this).removeClass('edit').addClass('save').text('save');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('save')){
            $(this).removeClass('save').addClass('edit').text('edit');
        }
        return false; // or not, you decide...
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mKe7N/).

Comment: This kinda works... now I have the problem how to I pass `$('.text').val()` to the save function? I keep getting `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell jquery that you will handle the click event, e.g.

```
$('.edit').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.content').html('<textarea class="text">' + content + '</textarea>');
  $('.text').focus();
  $(this).removeClass('edit').addClass('save').text('Save');
```

}

Which will hopefully stop the click event and only make the save trigger when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with the classes I would check the text instead - as you already have it hard coded it won't make much difference:

```
$('.edit').live('click', function() {
    var curText = $(this).text();
    if (curText === 'Edit') {
        $('.content').html('<textarea class="text">' + content + '</textarea>');
        $('.text').focus();
        $(this).removeClass('edit').addClass('save').text('Save');
    } else {
        $('.content').html($('.text').val()); 
        $(this).removeClass('save').addClass('edit').text('Edit');          
        // Ajax code to save new content
    }
});
```